# Do something after object and all it's related objects are saved

Tags: python, django

There are `Invoice` and `InvoiceItem` classes in my project

```
class Invoice(Model):
    ...
    pdf = FileField(...

    def save(...):
        super().save(...)
        self.generate_pdf()

    def generate_pdf(self):
        generate_pdf_from_self_and_invoiceitemset()
        save_pdf()

class InvoiceItem(...):
    item = ForeignKey('Invoice'...)
    ...
```

Simple - I want PDF file to be generated after `invoice` is created or modified. The problem is that this PDF depends not only on `invoice` but on it's `invoice_items` too.

So as you can see, the `generate_pdf()` method after `super().save()` generates `pdf` BEFORE `InvoiceItem`s are created or modified.

I want it to call the method right after last `InvoiceItem` was saved (or if not modified, when `Invoice` was saved).

How to do that?

I can put `generate_pdf()` into `InvoiceItem.save` method too but it would be time and resource consuming to generate `pdf` multiple times after any save.

I prefer to call method on model layer if possible so there is no chance somebody forget to put it inside new form or admin form.

Comment: Is using post_save signal an option? here's a link about its functionalities https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: No problem with post_save but it is called before InvoiceItem save() so I dont think it can help. Could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: What is saving the invoiceitems? Is this all being done in a view? Can you not do the PDF generation there too?

Comment: The point is, how do you know you have created the last **InvoiceItem**?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The thing is that user (admin) can create the Invoice from admin but there will be multiple places where other users can create the invoice. So that's why I'm looking for a way to define it once.

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto - yes, that's the main question.

Comment: Just asking if there is some standard way to do that. Otherwise I will go with calling it everywhere it should be called (UpdateView, CreateView, Admin etc.)

Comment: There isn't really, because there is no way of the Invoice knowing when there are no more invoiceitems to save. That's the job of whatever is saving those.

Comment: do you think about cron-jobs like scheduling task to solve this problem ?

Comment: You could "mark" an `Invoice` item as ready for finalising (i.e. PDF creation) in your views or forms and then run a task in the background that generates the PDF for ready invoices (and then mark them 'done'). But yeah, only your form or views know when an `Invoice` instance is ready.